# Check if a single point is within a camera's view

Tags: c#, slimdx, frustum

I've researched frustum culling and most solutions present ways to find bounding boxes on mesh objects. My point isn't a mesh and has no size, it's simply a coordinate in 3D worldspace.  The goal isn't to relieve graphics processing, it's simply to find if a point in worldspace would be within the camera's view.

This is my code for calculating the frustum planes, taken from http://www.richardssoftware.net/2013/08/hardware-instancing-and-frustum-culling.html

```
public Frustum(Matrix vp)
{
    _frustum = new[] {
        //left
        new Plane(vp.M14 + vp.M11, vp.M24 + vp.M21, vp.M34 + vp.M31, vp.M44 + vp.M41),
        // right
        new Plane(vp.M14 - vp.M11, vp.M24 - vp.M21, vp.M34 - vp.M31, vp.M44 - vp.M41),
        // bottom
        new Plane(vp.M14 + vp.M12, vp.M24 + vp.M22, vp.M34 + vp.M32, vp.M44 + vp.M42),
        // top
        new Plane(vp.M14 - vp.M12, vp.M24 - vp.M22, vp.M34 - vp.M32, vp.M44 - vp.M42),
        //near
        new Plane(vp.M13, vp.M23, vp.M33, vp.M43),
        //far
        new Plane(vp.M14 - vp.M13, vp.M24 - vp.M23, vp.M34 - vp.M33, vp.M44 - vp.M43)
    };
    foreach (var plane in Planes)
    {
        plane.Normalize();
    }
}
```

Using those planes and either a Vector3 or Matrix, how can I tell if a point is within the camera view?

Comment: **Solve a simpler problem.** Suppose you had a single plane and a single point, and an orientation for the plane -- that is, some way to tell the "top" and "bottom" of the plane apart. Such a plane divides three-space into three distinct regions: the plane, the region "above" the plane, and the region "below" the plane. Describe an algorithm that takes an oriented plane and a point, and tells you which of the three regions the point is in. If you can solve this much easier problem then you can solve your frustum problem.

Comment: Hint 1: given a normal to a plane (which orients it), and a given point on the plane, there is a function whose zeros are the points on the plane. What is that function?  Hint 2: What do you know about the value of that function when given a point not on the plane?